# JavaFX - Different layouts in a custom ListCell

Tags: java, javafx, chat, javafx-8

I'm building a chat app using JavaFX. Now for chat messages display, I use a simple `ListView` of `ChatItem`s with a custom cell factory, `ChatCell`.

`ChatItem` could be a `ChatLabel` (server announcements, status change, etc), or a `ChatMessage` (message sent by self or other parties). And `ChatMessage` could be extended to show various content (just `ChatTextMessage` and `ChatImageMessage` for now)

My custom cell checks the type/characteristics of the item and provides the proper view accordingly.

I'd like to show a timestamp on each `ChatMessage` view on bottom right corner of the chat bubble. BUT if the text is only one line, I want the timestamp to show on an extra space on the right of the text. (kinda like WhatsApp chat or most chat apps).

Here's a demo:
[image]

My current implementation (shown in the demo) uses a boolean property in `ChatMessage` that determines if the view should be multiline or not. It checks it on every update. I also add a listener to `ListView` width and call `refresh()` when it changes. All of this seems excessive. And I don't think adding a "view-related" property to a "model" is a good design. Not to mention that on the first item update, the timestamp is not at the correct place for some reason.

How can I do this properly?

**UPDATE 1:**
I added a property extractor for the `ListView` items, and added a listener for the `ListView` width that calls `updateItem` on width changes. Now I don't have to call `refresh()`

Here is `ChatCell` class:

```
public class ChatCell extends ListCell<ChatItem> {

    private ChatItemView view;
    private InvalidationListener listViewListener;
    private InvalidationListener listViewWidthListener;

    public ChatCell() {
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        listViewWidthListener = e -> {
            updateItem(getItem(), isEmpty());
        };

        listViewListener = e -> {
            if(getView() == null) return;
            getView().unbindWidth();
            if(listViewProperty().get() != null) {
                getView().bindWidth(listViewProperty().get().widthProperty());
                listViewProperty().get().widthProperty().addListener(listViewWidthListener);
                listViewWidthListener.invalidated(listViewProperty().get().widthProperty());
            }
        };

    }

    public ChatItemView getView() {
        return view;
    }

    private void initChatLabelView() {
        view = new ChatLabelView();
    }

    private void initChatMessageView(ChatMessage message) {
        view = new ChatMessageViewWrapper(message);
    }


    private void resetView() {
        if(view == null) return;
        view.unbindWidth();
        listViewProperty().removeListener(listViewListener);
        if(getListView() != null)
            getListView().widthProperty().removeListener(listViewWidthListener);
        view = null;
    }

    private void newViewCreated() {
        listViewProperty().addListener(listViewListener);
        setGraphic(view);
        listViewListener.invalidated(listViewProperty());
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(ChatItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if(item == null || empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
            resetView();
        } else {
            // First-level comparison: Label vs. Message
            if(item.getViewType() == ViewType.LABEL) {
                if(view == null || !(view instanceof ChatLabelView)) {
                    resetView();
                    initChatLabelView();
                    newViewCreated();
                }

            }

            else if(item.getViewType() == ViewType.MESSAGE) {
                ChatMessage message = (ChatMessage) item;
                if(view == null || !(view instanceof ChatMessageViewWrapper)) {
                    resetView();
                    initChatMessageView(message);
                    newViewCreated();
                }
                else {
                    ChatMessageViewWrapper bubble = (ChatMessageViewWrapper) view;
                    // Second-level comparison: Self-message vs. other user message,
                    // Text vs. Image (or file), multiline vs. oneline 
                    if(  (bubble.getContentType() != message.getContentType())
                            || (bubble.isSelf() ^ message.isSelf()) 
                            || (bubble.isMultiline() ^ message.isMultiline())) {
                        resetView();
                        initChatMessageView(message);
                        newViewCreated();
                    }

                }

            }

            else {
                return;
            }

            view.setItem(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Orientation getContentBias() {
        return Orientation.HORIZONTAL;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I missed something, but can't you just use CSS's "float: right"?

Comment: That would wrap the timestamp if no more space is left, but put it right of the text when there is enough space.

Comment: Unfortunately, JavaFX CSS [doesn't support it.](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#intro)

Comment: Have you tried it? The JavaFX 8 CSS spec does not mention this limitation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#intro

Comment: I did actually try it after realizing it's not in the JavaFX 8 CSS spec, but no luck. I guess the whole 2.2 specs apply to 8, unless otherwise stated.